# angularjs nvd3 directive displaying half pie chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Hi im trying to create a pie chart using [angularjs-nvd3-directives](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/pie.chart.html), but my charts is divided by half and i don't understand why if im setting the width and height, here is my code:

html:

```
<nvd3-pie-chart
                    data="exampleData"
                    id="exampleId"
                    width="550"
                    height="350"
                    x="xFunction()"
                    y="yFunction()"
                    showlegend="true"
                    tooltips="true"
                    showlabels="true"
                    labeltype="percent"
                    labelthreshold="0.5">
                    <svg width="550" height="350"></svg>
        </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

javascript:

```
$scope.exampleData = [{
            key: "5 Stars",
            y: 25
        }, {
            key: "4 Stars",
            y: 32
        }, {
            key: "3 Stars",
            y: 99
        }, {
            key: "2 Stars",
            y: 120
        }, {
            key: "1 Stars",
            y: 64
        }];

        $scope.xFunction = function () {
            return function (d) {
                return d.key;
            };
        };

        $scope.yFunction = function () {
            return function (d) {
                return d.y;
            };
        };
```

thanks for you time!!!

edit-> new code:

```
              <nvd3-pie-chart
                        data="exampleData"
                        id="exampleId"
                        width="500"
                        x="xFunction()"
                        y="yFunction()"
                        showlegend="true"
                        tooltips="true"
                        showlabels="true"
                        labeltype="percent">
                        <svg  width="1000" height="350"></svg>
             </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wrozi31bys3W1ss8PsFC?p=preview i found this plunker but i can't understand why width and height don't scale the chart evenly

Comment: I think it's because directive's target is to create circle - not ellipsis, so it gets the lower value of width and height and uses it to count a diameter.

Comment: i solve it!!!! the nvd3-pie-chart width manage the width of the background where the chart is and i think is multiplied by 2 and the svg manage the size of the pie but you have to include the legend space, my code look like this now (see edit)